# How can I create GDI Leaks in Windows Forms!

Tags: winforms, gdi+, gdi

I am investigating a GDI resource leak in a large application. In order to further my understanding of how these problems occur, I have created a very small application which I have deliberately made 'leaky'. Here is a simple user control which should result in the creation of 100 Pen objects:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    private List pens = new List();

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            pens.Add(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, i * 2, i * 2, 255 - i * 2))));
        }

        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(TestControl_Paint);
    }

    void TestControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pens[i], 0, i, Width, i);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I create an instance of my object and add it to a form, looking at my application with TaskManager I currently see ~37 GDI objects. If I repeatedly add new TestObject user controls to my form, I *still* only see ~37 GDI objects.

What is going on here! I thought that the constructor for System.Drawing.Pen would use the GDI+ API to create a new Pen, thus using a new GDI object.

I must be going nuts here. If I cannot write a simple test application that creates GDI objects, how can I create one which leaks them!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best Regards, Colin E.

Comment: Strange problem there, I agree. Have you verified whether the no. of GDI objects decreases from 37 if you loop *fewer* than 37 times?

Comment: Yes - the 37 GDI objects appears to relate to the overhead of the simple test application itself. It is nothing to do with the number of loops in the above code. I think OregonGhost (below) is onto something GDI+ is not using GDI handles, which I assumed it did! I wish there was some documentation out there that verified this.

Answer (score 2):

Does the GDI+ use GDI handles? I'm not sure, though I read somewhere that there is a .NET System.Drawing implementation that relies on bare GDI.

However, maybe you can try to find your leaks with a profiler like AQTime instead.

How are you sure your large app is leaking GDI handles? Is the count in Task Manager large? If so, are you always using GDI+, or also GDI? Does your test app GDI handle count increase if you create your control multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, that was my suspicion that GDI+ is not always using GDI handles. 

I am sure the large application leaks GDI handles. It uses a large number (>500) and this increases over time.

As to whether we are using GDI+ all the time, we only use System.Drawing which I presume only uses GDI+ - is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: ... related to this, if System.Drawing.Pen does not use a GDI handle, what resource am I freeing by Disposing of it? Sorry if my one question has become three!

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I read somewhere, as mentioned, that there is a System.Drawing implementation using GDI, while one would typically expect System.Drawing to use GDI+. Might have been on Windows CE or something. I'm also not sure whether creating window handles (forms and controls) can increase GDI handle count. In many instances when I was leaking some kind of handles, it was because of leaked controls rather than GDI+ things.

Comment: @Pen.Dispose: You are freeing the System.Drawing resource, and it is not your duty to find out what that exactly is. Can be the underlying GDI+ object, a GDI handle or some other thing.

Comment: This answer is correct; although he's not sure of it :P   `System.Drawing.Pen` is a wrapper around a GDI+ Pen (although that is an implementation detail that could change at any time). That explains *why* you are not seeing GDI resources being used, it's not using GDI resources. On the other hand `System.Drawing.Pen` *does* implement `IDisposable`, therefore are you are **required** to call `Dispose` when you are done with the object.

Answer (score 2):

You are not really leaking resources in your sample. Remove this code from your Load event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pens.Add(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, i * 2, i * 2, 255 - i * 2))));
    }
```

Your Paint event handler should look like this:

```
void TestControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, i * 2, i * 2, 255 - i * 2))), 0, i, Width, i);
    }
}
```

Now you will be leaking in every paint call. Start minimizing/restoring your Form and see GDI objects sky rocket...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Denis ... nice try, but have you actually tested this? I gave it a go and my application still only used a handful of GDI objects. This does not make sense!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leak a GDI object from .NET, then just create a GDI object and not release it:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint="CreatePen", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreatePen(int fnStyle, int nWidth, int crColor);

CreatePen(0, 0, 0); //(PS_SOLID, 0=1px wide, 0=black)
```

Blingo blango, you're leaking GDI pens.

> i don't know *why* you want to create GDI leaks. But your question asked how to create GDI leaks from a WinForm - so there it is.

Comment: You should also mention the REASON this works in native code (P/Invoke) but not the managed GDI/GDI+ implementation. I believe it has something to do with .NET garbage collecting the GDI/GDI+ resources.

Comment: @IDWMaster: .NET garbage collector has no ability to "collect" native resource (e.g. GDI handles). Any .net code that does P/Invoke to allocate a GDI handle is also responsible for doing a P/Invoke to release them. Fortunately every object in the .NET framework takes care to do this. The garbage collector has nothing to do with that.

Comment: The GC can call a destructor on the object though, which could; in turn free the unmanaged resource.

Comment: An object's finalizer *might* call `.Dispose` for you - but it's purely  a "*save-your-ass bonus*" thing. It isn't required; the object author is not required to help you clean up after yourself by calling `Dispose` for you. Either way, it is `Dispose`, not the garbage collector, that is freeing managed resources. The garbage collector doesn't know how to free unmanaged resources; it doesn't even know how to call `Dispose`. And if the object's finalizer doesn't *call* Dispose then you don't even get that save-your-ass safety net.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following blog may have answered this question:

[Using GDI Objects the Right Way](http://ozgur.ozcitak.com/blog/2009/12/23/using-gdi-objects-the-right-way.html)

The GDI objects that aren't explicitly disposed should be implicitly disposed by their finalizes.
(Bob Powell has also mentioned this issue in [GDI+ FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006052218/http://bobpowell.net/disposing_of_resources.aspx) )

But I doubt if the CLR garbage collector can remove GDI resources so quickly that we can't even see memory usage changes from TaskManager. Maybe current GDI+ implementation doesn't use GDI.

I've tried the following piece of code to generate more GDI objects. But I still couldn't see any changes of the number of GDI handles.

```
void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r.Next()))), 0, i, Width, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler only use one handle.

If I in delphi create a lot of fonts I just take memory
but if I use the WinAPI `CreateFont()` I take GDI objects.

Answer (score 0):

Create two buttons on a form. Inside each button, add the following code. In one button, comment out the Dispose method.

```
    Form _test = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        _test = new Form();
        _test.Visible = false;
        _test.Show();
        _test.Hide();
        _test.Dispose();
    }
```

The button with the Dispose commented out shows you the leak. The other shows that Dispose causes the User and GDI handles to stay the same.

[This](http://ozgur.ozcitak.com/blog/2009/12/23/using-gdi-objects-the-right-way.html) is probably the best page I've found that explains it.